# WebOrb.net / Alternatives

Tags: .net, push, amf, server-push, weborb

I'm working on an online forex trading system and a while back we have decided to use weborb for .net.

The decision was made mainly because we already have a pretty solid .net backbone that was built for the current HTML website.

This decision is turning out to be very problematic for some reasons.

1. WebOrb client SDK is not a supported product and it has it's share of bugs and quirks you have to deal with.
2. WebOrb support while developing the product is very far from what you would expect

So, my question is actually divided into 2 question

1. is anyone here using WebOrb.net for production use in a system with multiple users/push data and more...?
2. Do you know any alternatives for a server that will communicate with a flex client side?

I know FluorineFX but I did not find any serious discussions about people ever using it for production.

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try use this projects:

- [Fluorine Fx](http://www.fluorinefx.com/) - Open Source
- [WCF Flash Remoting](http://wcfflashremoting.codeplex.com/) - Open Source

I successfully tried the Fluorine Fx and currently I'm testing the WCF Flash Remoting.

Answer (score 0):

I tried WebOrb.net and found the same things. Instead what worked for me is to **generate a web service façade** that exposed the functionality **already present in .NET classes** used within the website project. This also means all that functionality is now available using pretty much any technology, not just the proprietary interface WebOrb.net provides.

Answer (score 0):

This has been a persistent problem but the adoption of generate a web service façade exposes the functionality that is already present in `.NET` classes used within the website project. To eradicate this problem, one should also try the adoption of Fluorine Fx - Open Source and `WCF` `Flash Remoting` - Open Source. This should eradicate the problem and give better results.